# Обработчик кнопок в Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В DialogFragment выдает ошибку если в лайоте я указываю android:onclick="onClickCancel" и в активити откуда вызывается диалогфрагмент создаю метод

```
public void onClickCancel(View view){
    dlg1.dismiss();
    log("onlcickcancel");
}
```

когда кликаю выдает ошибку

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method 
onClickCancel(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button5'
```

писал во фрагменте

```
 view.findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
 Log.i("fr", "dismiss");
        }
    });
```

а он даже не реагирует, что я делаю не так.

сейчас пишу вот так

```
public class AddCommentFragment extends DialogFragment   implements View.OnClickListener
```

......

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_comment, null);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);


......
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button6:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

тоже не реагирует

вызываю фрагмент в активити 
df.show();

xml кнопок

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Введите сюда ваш комент"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText4" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так: добавить реализацию интерфейса OnClickListener в определении класса

```
public class Dialog1 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener
```

убрать в layout'e свойство android:onclick="onClickCancel", но добавить id:

```
android:id="@+id/btn1"
```

в OnCreateView типа такого:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog1, null);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
```

и затем OnClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn1:
      dismiss();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно потому, что в xml:

```
android:onclick="cancelClick",
```

а в коде:

```
public void onClickCancel.
```

Comment: нет это я писал вручную здесь, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Тогда xml в студию